# Why is the ThreadDeath class not called ThreadDeathError instead?

Tags: java, error-handling, throwable

Almost all Error subclasses in Java include the "-Error" suffix in their names, but not ThreadDeath. Why is this? This makes it hard to remember if it is a subclass of Error or Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadocs for `ThreadDeath` say this:

> An application should catch instances of this class only if it
> must clean up after being terminated asynchronously.  If
> `ThreadDeath` is caught by a method, it is important that it
> be rethrown so that the thread actually dies.

and

> The class `ThreadDeath` is specifically a subclass of
> `Error` rather than `Exception`, even though it is a
> "normal occurrence", because many applications catch all
> occurrences of `Exception` and then discard the exception.

What it is saying is that an application should treat `ThreadDeath` differently from **both** `Exception` **and** (other) `Error` classes.

Since the exception should be treated differently, it makes sense to use a class name that doesn't fit the normal patterns.

---

However, this should be of historic interest anyway.  The `Thread.stop()` method that throws this was deprecated over 20 years ago.  Your code shouldn't use `stop()`, and hence should not need to concern itself with this exception.  And neither should you.